# Ruby - Changing the date part of a Time instance

Tags: ruby, datetime, time

I have a Time instance curr_time with the value of Time.now and another String target_date with the value, say, "Apr 17, 2010". How do I get the date part in the variable curr_time change to the value of target_date ?

```
>> curr_time
=> Sun Feb 21 23:37:27 +0530 2010
>> target_date
=> "Apr 17, 2010"
```

I want curr_time to change like this:

```
>> curr_time
=> Sat Apr 17 23:37:27 +0530 2010
```

How to achieve this?

Comment: If you use Ruby on Rails however, there's a separate `Time` class with a `.change()`: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Time.html#method-i-change

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Time objects are immutable, so you have to create a new Time object with the desired values. Like this:

```
require 'time'
target = Time.parse(target_date)
curr_time = Time.mktime(target.year, target.month, target.day, curr_time.hour, curr_time.min)
```

Answer (score 16):

If you use **activesupport** (e.g. in a `rails` environment, or by

```
require 'active_support'
require 'active_support/core_ext/date_time'
```

)

Example of changing Time object.

```
>> t = Time.now
=> Thu Apr 09 21:03:25 +1000 2009
>> t.change(:year => 2012)
Thu Apr 09 21:03:25 +1000 2012
```

Comment: Only works on Rails: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Time.html#method-i-change, very useful though

Answer (score 3):

Try this one:

```
Time.parse(target_date) + curr_time.sec + curr_time.min * 60 + curr_time.hour * 60 * 60
=> Sat Apr 17 19:30:34 +0200 2010
```

You will get the DateTime with the Date from target_date and the Time from curr_time.

Comment: Just edited my answer (I did not get you right the first time...).

Comment: You could also state it as: Time.parse(Time.now.to_date.to_s) + time.sec.seconds + time.min.minutes + time.hour.hours